# HP Officejet 4500 G510n-z Not Showing up in Remote Desktop (Terminal Services)

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, wifi, windows-terminal-services, printer

I installed this printer on a windows XP machine.  First using the wireless option, and later using USB.

In both cases when I connect to my other computer (also Windows XP) via terminal services and check printers in the local resources tab it does not show up on the remote session.

I used to have a Samsung connected to my local computer over USB and and that worked fine over terminal services.

**Things I tried so far:**

I did read this page and installed the software fix on both computers: [(Printers that use ports that do not begin with...)](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;q302361)

I installed the minimum HP software install on the remote computer and that didn't help either.

I also tried running the add new printer wizard on the remote computer:

I selected "local printer attached to this computer" and did not check the "automatically.." option.
On the next page of the wizard I can select an option for "use the following port".
I see options for TS001 through TS009 there.
I'm assuming those are coming from the local machine.
I tried clicking each one and then checking "have disk" and pointing it to C:\3be8dc611b11322e8ddf8a67\i386\msxpsdrv.inf [1](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;q302361) but for every single TS00.. port it says "The specified location does not contain information about your hardware."

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm pretty stuck at this point.

[1](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;q302361) C:\3be8dc611b11322e8ddf8a67 is the folder I extracted the HP driver software to after I downloaded it.

Comment: Are the computers on the same network?  Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just share the printer and access it via the network?

Comment: No, unfortunately they're not on the same network.  They're at two different locations.